# How to use control symbols using \expandafter?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Suppose I want to typset `P\' olya` correctly in TeX but suppose my computer does not have the key invoking the character/symbol `'` (This is of purely theoretical interest). Now, TeX lets you use `\rq` to represent that symbol. Then how do I typeset the word Polya correctly using these tools?

The first command that comes to mind is `\expandafter`, however, both
`\expandafter\\lq` or `\expandafter\{\lq}` give me errors and do not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we have, in `plain.tex`

```
508 \def\lq{`} \def\rq{'}
```

(line number added for reference), you can just type

```
\csname\rq\endcsname
```

that will expand `\rq` to `'` and build a control sequence token out of this.

---

You can't use `\expandafter` that way:

```
\expandafter\\lq
```

is four tokens

```
\expandafter•\\•l•q
```

(the bullet just separates tokens), so you are trying to expand `l`, which does nothing at all, then put the expansion after the `\\` token (that in plain TeX happens to be defined); the result is

```
lptq
```

which is not very helpful. `;-)`

Similarly, `\expandafter\{\lq\}` is four tokens

```
\expandafter•\{•\lq•\}
```

Here `\lq` is expanded to `'` and you get

```
\{'\}
```

Comment: so csname is a primitive control sequence?

Comment: @Kun Yes, a very helpful one.